# My Nginx, do proxy_pass once on every 2 attempt

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

This is my Nginx code that I revers request `/nt` to another app. But it only works once on every 2 attempt:

```
events {

  worker_connections 32000;
  use epoll;
  accept_mutex on;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {

  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  reset_timedout_connection on;
  gzip off;
  access_log off;
  keepalive_timeout 0;
  client_max_body_size 20m;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  access_log /var/log/openresty/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/openresty/error.log;

  real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

  limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=perip:5m;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:5m rate=100r/s;
  limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=phplimit:10m rate=3r/s;

  server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    limit_conn perip 5;
    limit_req zone=one burst=20 nodelay;
    limit_req_status 444;
    limit_conn_status 444;
    root /usr/local/openresty/nginx/html/default;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location /nt {

      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_connect_timeout 10;
      proxy_send_timeout 30;
      proxy_read_timeout 30;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      limit_req_status 444;
      proxy_pass http://$proxy;
    }
  }
}
```

This is request headers that revers to the app on **correct** attempt:

```
{ 
    host: 'NGONX REVERSE PROXY SERVER IP',
    'x-forwarded-for': 'CLIENT IP',
    connection: 'close',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent':
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    accept:
     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

And This is request headers that revers to the app on **incorrect** attempt:

```
{ 
    host: '127.0.0.1:3000', # MY APP URL
    connection: 'close',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent':
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    accept:
     'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'
}
```

Why it is happening?

Comment: Looks like the incorrect atempt doesn't even enter that location block. Can you look for the different configurations you have on that nginx config and if the request is exactly the same each time you try? (Sometimes cache can get you). You know that because there is no "x-forwarded-for" header in the second one. Nginx (or something else) is catching that connection on another connection. If you can share an anonymitzed nginx configuration so we can search for problems it'll help us helping you.

Comment: @flaixman I updated first block of codes.